# Under what angle should we kick a ball at the foot of a hill in such a way that it falls back to us?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Under what angle should we kick a ball situated at the foot of a hill with incline $\varphi$ so it falls back to the starting point? 
 Find the solution for the first rebound. 
 Under what angle should we kick a ball so it returns after n-rebounds?

Here is a rough sketch: 
[image: Kicking a ball]
When I started solving this problem I first asked myself: 

 Which conditions will ensure that the ball will rebound directly back to us after 1.rebound (I defined 1.rebound after how many times the ball touches the incline ground)?
Which conditions for n-rebounds?

Any help is welcomed! 
 I neglected the drag force of air and simplified the shape of a hill.

Comment: What does the dotted line represent?

Comment: It is good that you identified the first question to ask yourself. Next you should try to answer that question.